# Quicksort algorithm from a textbook fails to properly sort an array

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I recently started to learn about the Quicksort. The textbook showed an example of recursive quicksort. However, even after copying everything from the textbook *(so please forgive me if the name of the array and methods are not appropriate)*, the result was not so good.

It seemed like the algorithm couldn't reach the second partition of the array.

Here is the example from the textbook:

```
1       class Quicksort {
2           static void qsort(int items[]) {
3               qs(items, 0, items.length-1);
4           }
5       }
6   
7   
8       private static void qs(int items[], int left, int right) {
9           int i, j;
10          int x, y;
11          
12          i = left; j = right;
13          x = items[(left+right)/2];
14          System.out.println("Comparand is " + x);
15      
16          do {
17              while((items[i] < x) && (i < right)) i++;
18              System.out.print(items[i]);
19              while((x < items[j]) && (j > left)) j--;
20              System.out.println(" and " + items[j]);
21          
22              if(i <= j) {
23                  y = items[i];
24                  items[i] = items[j];
25                  items[j] = y;
26                  i++; j--;
27              }
28          } while (i <= j);
29      
30          for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
31              System.out.print(items[i]);
32          System.out.println("");
33      
34          if(left < j) qs(items, left, j);
35          if(i < right) qs(items, i, right);
36          }
37       }
```

...and here is the result:

```
Original array: 3164597
Comparand is 4
6 and 4
3146597
Comparand is 1
3 and 1
1346597
Sorted array: 1346597
```

Please let me know which part is wrong and how should I fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)   // line 30, i == 0
    System.out.print(items[i]);     // line 31
System.out.println("");             // line 32, i == items.length
```

You're using a local variable `i` to loop through your array. But by doing so, you overwrite the value of `i` set by the partition loop above.

Use another variable to loop through your array:

```
for (int t = 0; t < items.length; t++)
    System.out.print(items[t]);
System.out.println("");
```

Or better yet, use a *foreach* loop to avoid this type of errors:

```
for (item : items)
    System.out.print(item);
System.out.println("");
```

Comment: I... I don't know how to thank you! I cannot believe that the textbook made such a stupid mistake and I didn't even realize it! Thank you!!!